# dynamically add the fields to the class fulfilling the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

i have a problem with TypeScript types

The intention is to add dynamically, the fields to the Doff class, but that these exist in the interface MyInterface.

Situation:

```js
export interface MyInterface {
  position?: any;
  test?: any;
}

class Doff implements MyInterface { // <-- ERROR 1
  constructor() {
    // for the example it is direct assignment, 
    // here is a loop that reads the fields and adds them 1 to 1
    
    const field = "position" as keyof MyInterface;
    
    this[field] = true; // <<-- ERROR 2
  }
  
  public four = 4;
}
console.log("OBJ >> ", new Doff());

/* 
> ERROR 1
Type 'Doff' has no properties in common with type 'MyInterface'


> ERROR 2
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression
 of type 'keyof MyInterface' can't be used to index type 'Doff'.
  Property 'position' does not exist on type 'Doff'.

*/
```

Comment: Error1: class Doff must have the properties from the MyInterface interfase and it doest have. Test and position are not implemented in the class.

Comment: @Firewizz I understand that, but theoretically they are optional, it would not be necessary to define them explicitly, or no?

Comment: For error2: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Comment: I dont think it is optional, just nullable. Interfaces force you to use the fields. The way you are using it I would use a base class and extend.